# Create tag synonym between 'て-form' and 'te-form'

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

Both of these are in the front page right now.  Could someone with the relevant permissions make them synonyms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and created a synonym from [te-form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/te-form) to [て-form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%a6-form) and copied over the tag wiki excerpt.